# Metro Bundler Looking for JS files in react-native directory

Tags: react-native

I am having a weird issue with React native over here. Maybe it is not even RN, but the Metro Bundler.

I have literally just created a brand new project using

> react-native init TestProject

After this, I simply ran

> react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 7"

Usually when I run-ios, the Metro bundler will, for example, look inside "/Users/fred/Documents/Development/TestProject" - right where my index.js file resides.

However - for some reason now, and on every new project that I create - it now looks at this path:
[image]

And it results in this error:
[image]

I have also tried to change the project root path in the `metro.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  projectRoot: path.resolve(__dirname),
};
```

But it does not seems to work.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and perhaps how I can fix it?

Please let me know if I missed anything which I should have posted here.

EDIT 1:

I have managed to get it to run in a way that I don't like that much.
Once I have run `react-native run-ios`, and the console comes up with the incorrect `node_modules/react-native` JS Metro Bundler console, I close that console, and KEEP the simulator open.

Then I run this command `react-native start --reset-cache`, and 'Command + R' the Simulator - which causes the correct path to execute. See these screenshots:

[image]

Then close the metro bundler console, and run `react-native start --reset-cache`:

[image]

Here we can see that the bundler now looks at the correct root path:
[image]

And then I just `Command + R` the Simulator:
[image]

Now, although I can continue working for now - I mean, WHY is this happening now? I have always just used the good old `react-native run-ios` and all was good. To do things this way is just plain cumbersome and unnecessary.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT 2:

I am now here - where I change the root string where it is causing the problem at:

`node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js`

Inside of the `setupAndRun()` function.

> const root = options.projectRoot ? _path().default.resolve(options.projectRoot) : process.cwd();

Anyone perhaps know why this line is causing an issue?

Answer (score 1):

So - after a month, I realised something - I `was doing this within the Visual Studio Code Terminal`. I simply switched to my main terminal not within VS Code, and `BOOM`, it was working as expected. `Tried it within VS Code, and it failed!` Found the culprit! Nothing related to react native or metro bundler! Damn you VS Code! Still love you though!

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: run in separate console:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

2) Or fix bug in `"@react-native-community/cli": "1.11.2"` using `patch-package`:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js b/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js
index 7fa03a8..171e019 100644
--- a/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js
+++ b/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js
@@ -198,7 +198,15 @@ async function setupAndRun() {


   const options = (0, _minimist().default)(process.argv.slice(2));
-  const root = options.projectRoot ? _path().default.resolve(options.projectRoot) : process.cwd();
+
+  var path = require('path')
+  var root
+  // Fix bug caused by removed projectRoot: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/484#issuecomment-508787630
+  if (process.argv[1].endsWith('node_modules/react-native/cli.js') && options['_'][0] == 'start')
+    root = path.normalize(process.cwd() + '/../..')
+  else
+    root = options.projectRoot ? _path().default.resolve(options.projectRoot) : (process.cwd() );
+
   const reactNativePath = options.reactNativePath ? _path().default.resolve(options.reactNativePath) : (() => {
     try {
       return _path().default.dirname( // $FlowIssue: Wrong `require.resolve` type definition
diff --git a/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel b/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Visual Studio Code, please install: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native

This sets the path correctly and provides a number of Command Palette commands for using the Packager.